# tinyMCE is an object in WordPress but "tinyMCE.init is not a function"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to add tinyMCE to a form field in WordPress. The form itself is generated by a plugin (JobRoller). The site already has a template and child templates that I was told I should not touch. My solution was to create a simple plugin that enqueues a JavaScript with both tinyMCE CDN and the code below.

The code below is all the JavaScript I'm adding.

```
if ( typeof( tinyMCE ) == "object" && typeof( tinyMCE.execCommand ) == "function" ) {
    alert('b');
    tinyMCE.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        plugins: 'textcolor link paste',
        height: 300,
        menubar: false,
        toolbar: [
          'bold italic underline strikethrough subscript superscript bullist numlist alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify link unlink',
          'formatselect forecolor copy cut paste pastetext removeformat indent outdent undo redo'
        ]
    });
}
```

When I run, I get the "b" from `alert('b');` but also get this message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: tinyMCE.init is not a function
```

If  type of tinyMCE is an object and execCommand is a function, how is it possible that tinyMCE.init is not a function?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use the dev console in your browser (f12 usually) and check the console for load errors. If there's a file missing, for example, the library or jquery version library (as suggested here: http://community.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=21116) then it wouldn't load properly.

Comment: I suggest you look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor and https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-use-the-tinymce-editor-for-fields-in-my-custom-post-type

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by conflict with a CKEditor plugin that the site owner had installed. Deactivating the plugin solved the issue.